# Vue Component in Laravel Blade won't render unless renamed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have made a Vue component built in a Laravel application for rendering a series of address fields:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label for="address_line_1">Address line 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="address_line_1" name="address_line_1" placeholder="Address line 1" :value="addressLine1" @input="setAddressLine1($event.target.value)" :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.address_line_1 }" required>
    </div>

    . . .
</template>

<script>

    import { mapActions } from "vuex";

    export default {

        props: {
            addressLine1: { type: String },
            addressLine2: { type: String },
            city: { type: String },
            province: { type: String },
            postalCode: { type: String },
            country: { type: String },
            module: { type: String } ,
            initErrors: { type: Object },
        },

        data() {
            return {
                errors: this.initErrors || {}
            }
        },

        methods: {
            ...mapActions('collection', ['setAddressLine1', 'setAddressLine2', 'setCity', 'setProvince', 'setPostalCode', 'setCountry']),
        },
    }

</script>
```

The file is in a components directory names Address.vue, it's includes in my application templates as:

```
<address
    module="collection"
    address-line1="{{ old('address_line_1', session('collection.address_line_1')) }}"
    address-line2="{{ old('address_line_2', session('collection.address_line_2')) }}"
    city="{{ old('city', session('collection.city')) }}"
    province="{{ old('city', session('collection.city')) }}"
    postal-code="{{ old('postal_code', session('collection.postal_code')) }}"
    country="{{ old('country', session('collection.country')) }}"
    :init-errors='@json($errors->messages(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)'
></address>
```

And included in app.js (simplified here)

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import Address from './components/Address.vue'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Address },
    store: store,
});

require('./bootstrap');
```

The component does not render on the page at all. There are no JavaScript errors. Other included components are working fine.

However, I have found that if rename all references to the component to e.g. AddressX and  then it renders and functions as expected.

Any clues as to why this might be?

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-reference/html-address-tag.php